# Passing RequestParams in the URL with AngularJS to Spring MVC backend

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have a URL mapping on my Spring REST controller that expects the URL to have three optional request parmeters. I have used `@RequestParam` annotation to define three optional parameters in the method that I defined below.
The URL works fine when I use a browser to hit the same.

The problem is when I try to hit the same url with my AngularJS service. I have worked with `PathVariables` in the past but am not sure how to pass these `RequestParam` variables into the URL.

Angular Service:

```
$resource(configuration.get('wsUrlPrefix') + 'abc/xyz/:page/:size/:sortData', {}, serviceConfig)
```

The URL turns out to be something like this:

> http://localhost:8080/abc/xyz//10?sortdata=%7B%22orderType%22:null,%22oEDistrictNbr%22:null,%22orderNumber%22:null,%22mainLine%22:null%7D

and the backend is not able to recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your sortdata parameter is an object, e.g. like this:

```
{ 
  orderType: null,
  eEDistrictNbr:null
  ..
}
```

So when this is encoded it will become like in your question (escaped chars, etc)

One way to fix it is to make sure your parameters are always strings or numbers, by deconstructing your object into simple primitives, e.g.

```
$resource(configuration.get('wsUrlPrefix') + 'abc/xyz/:page/:size/:sortDataOrderType/:sortDataEDistricNr/...', {}, serviceConfig)
```

Comment: Yes thanks. But in order to pass url parameters I used the ? symbol at the end of the param name. It worked thanks.